# How to access the SignalR Hub arguments from [Authorize()]?

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, claims-based-identity, signalr-hub

I'm making a signalr hub for a chat app (it's not really, but lets pretend it is).
I have my authorization set up so that user can be invited to a room by the creator of the room. So there's a table that stores who owns what, and who has been granted access.

This is good. Next steps were to add claims so that I didn't have to check who had access to what on every request. I check once when a user tries to join the chat room, add their claims, and send them to the page that starts the signalr connection.

Now I want to use the [authorize] decorator on my hubs, instead of throwing boilerplate

```
user.Claims.Any(x=> x.ClaimType == $"CanJoinRoom_{RoomId}");
```

everywhere.

I've read up on how to make custom policy based authorization here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies#security-authorization-policies-based

I have every piece I need except one: the actual arguments that specifies the room id. I have been able to hack something from

```
[MyCustomAuthorizeMethod(this.Context.Request.Form["data"])]
```

but this seems a bit ugly, and to make it work I have to serialize this json

```
{"H":"myhubname","M":"Initialize","A":[39],"I":0}
```

Which seems really hacky. I'd much prefer to pass the RoomId as a parameter.
It is just one line down but seems a world away. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: You are doing this wrong. What you hacked happens to work because you are using long polling once a different transport will be picked you won't be able to access this. I don't know what you want to do with the data but hubs are transient - i.e you will get a new instance for each invocation so if you want to store something in the hub then it won't work. Why don't you implement your logic in the `Initialize` method you are trying to invoke?

Comment: I'm pretty annoyed that signalr doesn't provide clean apis for meta-data about the call, or any sort of data structure. You'd think after going through all the work of actually wiring up the invocation that this would be trivial. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you need metadata (not sure what it would be though) if your method is being called - so you have method name and parameters? If you need metadata (whatever it is) create a meta hub function and dispatch from there. Alternatively look at IHubRequestParser or IParameterResolver but it probably will get hacky.

Comment: Because not all relevant code to the hub takes place within the function call. I need something for a custom authorize. IE [Authorize(param goes here)]

Comment: You can apply `Authorize` attribute on a hub method.

Comment: Not sure what the compiler has to do with it but there is a topic in the docs about this: https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization and also on msdn (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) which says: _Apply to Hubs and Hub methods to authorize client connections to Hubs and authorize client invocations of Hub methods._

Comment: Look at this line very carefully: [MyCustomAuthorizeMethod(this.Context.Request.Form["data"])]

Comment: It's not the compiler - it's the language that does not allow using non-const values in attributes because attributes are processed at compile time.

Comment: ok, that's new information, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible because attributes are computed at compile time and therefore cannot have variables. Thanks to Pawel for pointing that out.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1168070/pawel

Answer (score 0):

If you want to authorize invoking a given method you can put the [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) on the hub method. You may also find [this post](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization) on hub authorization and authentication helpful.

Comment: I know how to tack on an [Authorize()]. I don't know why you would think I wouldn't know about something I'm typing.

Comment: Because in a comment you deleted you said you thought that the Authorize attribute can only be put on Hub class and not on Hub methods.